# Mule with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mule, esb

I have a Mongodb query in the mule flow as below and targets the output to float variables.

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.service]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <mongo:find-objects-using-query-map config-ref="Mongo_DB" collection="hosts" doc:name="query hosts">
        <mongo:query-attributes>
            <mongo:query-attribute key="id">45</mongo:query-attribute>
        </mongo:query-attributes>
    </mongo:find-objects-using-query-map>
</enricher>
```

How to use mule expression to access the domain value in the output json below? Thanks.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57e230df56a0750c39ad395d"} , "id" : "45" , "domain" : "www.abc.com" , "port" : "80" , "path" : "posts/1"}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `JsonPath` in `MEL` to query JSON message `payloads` for filtering or enrichment like this `#[json:domain]`